# Why is AngularJS not autobinding property on page load? Very simple example included

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is an example of an Angular controller with two properties on the $scope. The firstName property is set to a function object (**I understand that this is set to a function object, and not the string being returned by the function!**) and the lastName property is set to a string.

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function NameCtrl($scope){
        $scope.firstName = function() {return "John"; };
        $scope.lastName = 'Smith';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NameCtrl">
    First name:<input ng-model="firstName" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Last name:<input ng-model="lastName" type="text"/>
    <br>
    Hello {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/hifutaxozo/1/edit

Although it's silly that I would have the property set to a function, bear with me here. I'm just curious about the internals of AngularJS here. In the text box, upon binding, I get the string representation of the function, which makes sense. In the HTML text though however, I do not get the string representation of the function. However, if I make changes to the function string in the textbox after angular has bound it, then the changes get reflected in the HTML. Why does the string representation of the function not get bound in the HTML text while it does in the input box?

Answer (score 2):

An `ng-model` must not be a function, change:

`$scope.firstName = function() {return "John"; };`

to

`$scope.firstName =  "John";`

And when you want to render the output of a function you need to evaluate the function first:

`Hello {{firstName()}} {{lastName}}`

But yea, your `ng-model` can't be a function.

Comment: Your second part isn't correct. As he shows, you can write `{{firstName}} {{lastName}}` event though `firstName` is a function.

Comment: @KjellIvar not really, if you run his sample john is not rendering :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the angular developers have chosen to run `toString()` on whatever you try to pass to `ng-model` (at least for input type=text). This makes sense, as it has to be put in a textbox, and it has to be editable by the user. Whatever you put into a input type=text should be a string anyway :) Running a function would in that case don't make much sense.

While in the HTML template, you need to ouput a value, or object that it will bind to. {{firstName()}} will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object and a return function to get The name.
Try it with prototype.

```
  function NameCtrl($scope){
    var objectPerson = function()
    {
        this.name = "John";
    };

    objectPerson.prototype.GetName = function(){ return this.name ;};
    var something = new objectPerson();
    $scope.firstName = something.GetName()
    $scope.lastName = 'Smith';
  }
```

Why it isn't working like you do is a little bit strange to me to but i guess its because its expecting a string. If somebody has a clearer explanation why this is i would be thrilled

PS. i don't know if this is good style btw i simply say it returns what you want